# Difference between join and terminate

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Please take a look at the following code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def f(name):
    print 'hello', name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

You will see that the function calls, `start` and `join` have been called here. Infact, they are *always* called in the examples of the `multiprocessing` module in the python [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html).

Now the reason why `start` is called so is fairly obvious, its because it starts the process. However, `join` is different from totally ending the process, as told in the documentation:

> Block the calling thread until the process whose join() method is called terminates or until the optional timeout occurs.

So, from my understanding, `join()` is used to terminate the process. So why is not the `terminate()` function used in the examples of the documentation or `TerminateProcess()`?

And thus, that brings us to the main question, what is the difference between `join` and `terminate`? Ideally, what is `join`'s purpose and what is `terminate`'s purpose? Because they both seem be capable of doing the same thing according to the examples (correct me, if I'm mistaken).

I have so far discovered, that probably because `terminate` is different for both windows and linux, since windows has a different function for termination. Further reasons for the choice would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`join` is used to wait the process, not actively terminate the process, while `terminate` is used to kill the process.

Try following example (with / without `p.terminate()`):

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def f(name):
    time.sleep(1)
    print 'hello', name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.terminate() # <---
    p.join()
```

With `terminate`, you get no output.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what "wait the process" means?

Comment: I means: wait until the process has done its jobs (the function return) or killed.

Answer (score 6):

> So, from my understanding, `join()` is used to terminate the process.

No. Not even close. It tells the *calling* thread to *wait* until the other thread *has been terminated*, and then returns.

Comment: So, essentially, `join()` blocks program execution, right? Since its waiting.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac: It blocks thread execution. If it is called in the main thread, then it will appear as though the "program" is blocked, although other threads will run.

Answer (score 0):

The function `join()` is used to tell the calling process to wait.